# Visual Studio 2017 output window build verbosity

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2017, verbosity

Is there a way to stop VS 2017 from displaying the entire CL.exe and Link.exe command line in the build output window? This seems like a new development. It happens with some solutions but not with others. I cannot seem to figure out what controls this. I saw this lengthy discussion here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/11155/sporadically-show-command-line-parameters-in-outpu.html
which did not lead to any resolution.

P.S: Changing the MSBuild verbosity level to Quiet is not what I am looking for. I just want it to stop printing the compiler/linker command lines as these tend to be quiet large for our projects.